# How to get an expression for $\frac{e1}r$ out of these four equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the following equations:

$$y = g_2 \cdot e_3 \\
e_3 = e_2 - y \cdot h_2 \\
e_2 = g_1 \cdot e_1 \\
e_1 = r - h_1 \cdot e_2 - h_3 \cdot y$$

How can I get an expression of $\dfrac{e1}r$ in terms of $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$, $h_1$, $h_2$ and $h_3$?

Comment: Is the dot, multiplication or is it that the $e_{j}$'s are basis vectors and it is a scalar product?

Comment: It is multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first and third equations, replace $y$ and $e_2$ in the other two equations.  You now have two equations in two unknowns $e_1$ and $e_3$.

Comment: I don't want e3 to be in the final expression. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use one of the two remaining equations to write $e_3$ in terms of $e_1$, and substitute into the other.  I just thought that two equations would be easier than four.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's look at $e_{1}$ and substitute in all the others, in sequence.
\begin{eqnarray}
e_{1} &=& r-h_{1}.e_{2}-h_{3}.y \\
      &=& r-h_{1}e_{1}g_{1}-h_{3}g_{2}e_{3} \\
      &=& r-h_{1}e_{1}g_{1}-h_{3}g_{2}(e_{2}-yh_{2}) \\
      &=& r-h_{1}e_{1}g_{1}-h_{3}g_{2}e_{2}-yh_{3}g_{2}h_{2} \\
      &=& r-h_{1}e_{1}g_{1}-h_{3}g_{2}g_{1}e_{1}-yh_{3}g_{2}h_{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Now just collect like terms in $e_{1}$ and re-arrange to the form you need.

Comment: I said that I want the expression in terms of g1, g2, g3, h1, h2 and h3. In your solution, it contains y.

Comment: I didn't want to do absolutely everything for you, I'm sure you can take it form here.

Comment: The problem is that y is written in terms of e3, and e3 in terms of e2, and e2 in terms of e1, and e1 in terms of y. So can I really get rid of y?